# How is it possible to pull up an op amp's output to its negative or positive rail when its input is floating?

Tags: operational-amplifier

If signal source is varying between zero and 5V; and if we buffer this signal with an opamp which works with +10V supply or */-10V dual supply, is it then possible to pull up the op amp's output to its around -10V negative or around 10V positive rail when its input is floating(when the signal is decoupled from the opamp's input)? Can you show a topology example?

The following behaviour I mean:

input ---> opamp buffer --> output

10mV ------> opamp buffer ------> 10mV

5V ------> opamp buffer ------> 5V

Floating ------> opamp buffer ------> -opamp's negative rail(-10V) or positive rail +10V (but not zero V)

Edit:

To be more specific the following *[opamp](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT1007-LT1037.pdf)* buffer does not go to positive or negative rail when its input is floating:

[image]

So in simulation output is no behaving how I need. how can we modify this to obtain -15V or +15V output (around one of the rail voltages) when the input is floating?

***Edit for an answer:***

[image]

Comment: This website has a schematic editor.

Comment: your design specs are rather floppy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it then possible to pull up the op amp's output to its around -10V negative or around 10V positive rail when its input is floating?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTSAr3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A buffer amplifier with pull-down resistors. With SW1 closed the output follows the input. With SW1 open the output swings to -8 V.*

Here R1 pulls the input down to -8 V set by divider R2 and R3. I've chosen -8 V rather than -10 V to prevent latch-up which can happen with some op-amps if driven too close to the supply voltages. You can modify this to suit your device specifications.

For a positive default just connect R3 to +10 V instead.

---

Now that you've revealed what your application is - a wind vane using a 330° pot with a dead-zone I suggest the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJBhgo.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Adding C1 to the buffer input will hold the reading at the most recent value when the pot is disconnected.*

The advantage now is that the reading won't jump between V+ and GND every time you run off the top end of the pot and reconnect.

For this to work well you will need a very high impedance input op-amp with low bias currents and a low leakage capacitor.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Based on your circuit I will add a new schematics in LTspice and ask you couple of things about it.

Comment: Now I updated your circuit added to the question and it can be found here https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEQeL.png . So the input is coming from a 1k wind vane modelled in dashed rectangle in my drawing. For better precision I first needed to use larger resistors for R1 R2 and R3. I hope it is fine?

Comment: Besides that I have two questions: 1) I can only get very low offset with this LT1007 with dual supply. But when I use single supply precision opamps(such as zero drift) I never get such small offset as in dual supply, is that expected. I ask because it is easier to with single supply. 2) Do I need a feedback resistor with any value regarding this kind of load?

Comment: (0) Larger resistors should be fine. Your circuit will bias to 560 / (560 + 820) of Vss. (1) I'm not familiar with the LT1007. I don't understand what you are saying about small offset. Is your op-amp able to swing its output to GND? (2) OA1 is configured as a unity gain buffer. It has 100% negative feedback.

Comment: Thanks. But I think I will go for the first one since I and some other friends want to capture when the vane passing through dead band and omit those points in post analysis. I increased R1 to 100Meg and added C4 for wiper noise(suggested here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21297/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-potentiometer-to-measure-angle) and used a  low offset opamp for single supply operation. In simulation it works very good. Here is my final one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QAYW.png What do you think?

Comment: Given that your vane pot is 1k choosing 100M for the bias resistor is way over the top and PCB leakage, bias currents and capacitor leakage (not to mention any dampness in your outdoor pot) will completely swamp the 100M. 100k would give you an error of < 1%. Go with 470k.

Comment: Sorry my English I had difficulty understand what you meant in your last comment. Do you mean using 100Meg is not necessary or it will be problematic?

Comment: Your English is pretty good. I didn't know that you are not a native English speaker. You can add this into your user profile. OK. 100 MΩ is a very, very high resistance. Leakage across your PCB will be lower than that. If your op-amp has 10 nA input bias current then you will get V = IR = 10n × 100M = 1 V error on your output. If you change it to 470k then your error would be 10n × 470k = 0.47 mV. This would be much better!

Comment: The datasheet (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT1006.pdf)  says 10nA input bias current as you mentioned. But I stimulated the circuit in LTspice with 100 Meg and the difference between the input and output of the opamp buffer is only 1.5uV. Not anything like 1V.

Comment: Measure the input current to see what the sim is using. Is the pot connected or not?

Comment: Yes pot is connected like in the diagram I have linked before https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QAYW.png The currents at the opamp inputs are  around 9.45nA in simulation. But when I disconnect the pot the (means when the wiper is floating) the inverting input increases 1V more than voltage divider voltage (R2 R3) junction. So when the wiper is floating, the opamp outputs 9.1V instead of 8.1V which is fine for me. And when the poti is connected this issue does not happen and somehow the input current doesn't cause 1V increase at the ouput in this case. So do you think it is fine to keep 100Meg?

Comment: No. I have explained twice why you shouldn't. Your simulator does not have a PCB and is not in the real world which gets wet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can even ground the output (choose the output =0Vdc not PE Gnd) when operating from a battery +/- to make a bipolar or split supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx4lg0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A battery generally has a lower ESR for motors for surge currents than a Darlington buffer or even a SMPS. So be careful how you choose gnd and loads.